# With Python, how to attach a whole xlsx file into a docx file

Tags: python, excel, docx, ole

So im wondering if anyone know a python way to attach a whole xlsx file into a doc file, instead of manually "insert an object" feature. Im aware of manipulating the xlsx data and paste it on a docx file, but in this case, the data inside the xlsx file is not important. I just need to attach the file.

Example:
[image]

Comment: It seems [`python-docx`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) does not handle this kind of object. Lower level API, such as [`pywin32`](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32), may be required to reach your goal but it is platform dependent and requires Office to be installed.

Comment: That is not a problem, so thanks a lot, i will check that pywin32 lib, because by now i've just worked with openpyxl and python-docx. Thanks :)

Comment: probably not want you want to here, but commercial Docx4j Enterprise java can do this (it is called OLE insertion)